# Найти угол между векторами в диапазоне от 0 до 360 градусов

Tags: javascript, babylon.js

Добре. Недавно начал перенос проекта на новый движок и столкнулся с рофлами, я не могу найти полное значение круга в градусах, т.к. скрип по какой-то причине вычисляет только внутренний угол, не затрагивая внешний. Вопрос - каким образом нужно написать скрипт, чтобы получить углы как на изображении ниже(отсчёт ведётся от синей линии, а все вектора направлены от центральной точки)

P.S. сейчас выводит 45, 0, 90. Должно выводить 45, 180, 270

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.babylonjs.com/babylon.js"></script>
    <script>
        var mesharr = new BABYLON.Vector3(-6, 0, 6)

        var baseV1 = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 5);
        var baseV2 = new BABYLON.Vector3(-2, 0, 5);
        var direction

        var BaseVector = baseV1.subtract(baseV2);

        var pointA1 = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        var pointC1 = new BABYLON.Vector3(-2, 0, 2);

        var vectorAA = pointA1.subtract(pointC1);
        var angle_1 = angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees(BaseVector, vectorAA);
        console.log(angle_1);//ожидается 45, на вывод 45
        direction = vectorAA.dot(mesharr)
        // Проверка направления вектора
        if (direction > 0) {
                console.log('к точке')
            } else {
                console.log('от точки')
        }

        var pointE1 = new BABYLON.Vector3(-14, 0, 5);
        var pointF1 = new BABYLON.Vector3(-10, 0, 5);

        var vectorEE = pointF1.subtract(pointE1);
        var angle_2 = angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees(BaseVector, vectorEE);
        console.log(angle_2);//ожидается 180, на вывод 0
        direction = vectorEE.dot(mesharr)
        // Проверка направления вектора
        if (direction > 0) {
                console.log('к точке')
            } else {
                console.log('от точки')
        }

        var pointG1 = new BABYLON.Vector3(-7, 0, 13);
        var pointI1 = new BABYLON.Vector3(-7, 0, 15);

        var vectorGG = pointG1.subtract(pointI1);
        var angle_3 = angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees(BaseVector, vectorGG);
        console.log(angle_3);//ожидается 270, на вывод 90
        direction = vectorGG.dot(mesharr)
        // Проверка направления вектора
        if (direction > 0) {
                console.log('к точке')
            } else {
                console.log('от точки')
        }

        function angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees(v1, v2) {
            // Находим скалярное произведение векторов
            const dotProduct = v1.x * v2.x + v1.z * v2.z;
        
            // Находим длины векторов
            const v1Length = Math.sqrt(v1.x * v1.x + v1.z * v1.z);
            const v2Length = Math.sqrt(v2.x * v2.x + v2.z * v2.z);
        
            // Вычисляем угол между векторами
            let angle = Math.acos(dotProduct / (v1Length * v2Length));
        
            // Преобразуем радианы в градусы
            let degrees = angle * (180 / Math.PI);
        
            return degrees;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что вам нужен угол именно по часовой стрелке? // «Недавно начал перенос проекта» — под этой фразой вы подразумеваете, что раньше оно работало как надо? А как оно там работало тогда?

Comment: это я указал как дополнение, сейчас я прописываю новый функционал, и там необходима эта функция и да, требуется вычисление по часовой стрелке :)

Comment: Найти направление векторного произведения

Comment: @alexey-ten, ок, а как это сделать в трёхмерном пространстве?

Comment: Так у вас фактически двумерное пространство. Вообще нужно просто посчитать детерминант матрицы из двух векторов и если он отрицательный до прибавить к углу 180°

Comment: `if (v1.x * v2.z - v1.z * v2.x < 0) { degrees += 180; }`

Comment: @AlexeyTen выводит: 225, 0, 270. это уже более близко к моим требованиям, 0 - ок, можно на 180 подменить, но как получилось значение 225 заместо 45 градусов?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Внёс правку*

Comment: Спасибо. Какой может быть угол между векторами, если один из них нулевой? То есть не имеет направления? Во втором наборе вектора почти сонаправлены. В третьем тоже угол не большой. Тестовые вектора не соответствуют заявленным углам.

Comment: это набор точек для вектора, т.к. вектор строится по точкам, я указал набор, в котором указаны две точки, начальная и последняя

Comment: Базовый вектор горизонтальный. Не совпадает с картинкой.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Тестовые данные, как и весь код загружен в обновлённый вопрос

Comment: Я распечатал аргументы и результаты: `v1 { x: 2, y: 0, z: 0 } v2 { x: 2, y: 0, z: -2 } degrees 45.00000000000001` - правильно. `v1 { x: 2, y: 0, z: 0 } v2 { x: 4, y: 0, z: 0 } degrees 0` - правильно. `v1 { x: 2, y: 0, z: 0 } v2 { x: 0, y: 0, z: -2 } degrees 90` - правильно. Где ошибка?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy мне требуется вычислять полное значение, а не 180 в одну сторону и 180 в другую, вот в чём rofls

Comment: Ещё раз: все ваши примеры вычислены верно. Если вы хотите чтобы вам помогли исправить ошибку, пожалуйста, приведите эту ошибку в вопросе. Сейчас в вопросе нет ошибки.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy обратите внимание на P.S

Comment: Третий пример: на вход подаются вектора *(2, 0, 0)* и *(0, 0, -2)*. Ваша процедура считает что первый вектор нужно повернуть на 90 градусов по часовой стрелке, чтобы он совпал со вторым. Я тоже считаю что правильный ответ 90 градусов. Почему вы считаете что правильный ответ в этом примере 270, а не 90?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy потому что вычисление угла должно происходить от baseVector по часовой стрелке, вопрос - как это реализовать

Comment: Вектор *(2, 0, 0)* направлен вправо. Встаньте в этом направлении и повернитесь на 90 градусов вправо. Вы будете смотреть вниз. То есть ваше направление будет *(0, 0, -2)*. Откуда в этом примере может взяться 270?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy если я буду вести отсчёт против часовой - будет 270

Comment: Как вы измените второй пример? Там изначально вектора сонаправлены, угол между ними - ноль. Изменением системы отсчёта этот факт не изменить.

Answer (score 0):

#### Уточнение

Если я вас правильно понимаю - v1 это начальная координата вектора, v2 это конечная координата. В таком случае вот что мы сделаем.

#### Решение

```js
// Считаем базовые координаты вашего вектора
const difference = { x: v2.x - v1.x, y: v2.y - v1.y };
// Считаем угол тангенса с осью Y, но -y ставим так как отсчет начинается с минусовой части оси Y
let angle = Math.atan2(difference.x, -difference.y); 
// Прибавляем к результату Пи, так как полученный угол у нас будет в диапазоне [-π; π]
angle += Math.PI;
```

#### Результат

[image]

Comment: Вычислять угол между векторами как угол их разницы неверно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не совсем понял, что неправильно. Взгляните-ка на визуальный результат. Это не то что автор хотел?

Comment: Ваш код для векторов *[1, 0]* и *[0, 1]* выдаёт 45 градусов. Угол между ними *-90*.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ааа, я просто недопонял вопрос. Я считал не угол между векторами, а угол поворота вектора начиная с синей части.

Comment: @Leobuildru я ответил немного на другой вопрос. Мне снести ответ, или он может вам пригодиться?

Comment: выводит 360, 90, 315

Comment: @eccs0103 как хотите, но штука в любом случае полезная, может странствующим путникам стака это и пригодится :)

Answer (score 0):

`angleCcw` считает угол на который нужно повернуть первый вектор вокруг глобального нуля чтобы он совпал со вторым. Угол измеряется в радианах против часовой стрелки. Диапазон *(-π, π]*.

`angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees` меняет местами вектора, чтобы считать угол по часовой стрелке, исправляет диапазон на *[0, 2π)*, переводит радианы в градусы.

```js
const angleCcw = (v1, v2) => Math.atan2(
    v1.x * v2.z - v1.z * v2.x,
    v1.x * v2.x + v1.z * v2.z
);

function angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees(v1, v2) {
    let angle = angleCcw(v2, v1); // обратный порядок

    // приведение в диапазон [0, 2PI)
    if (angle < 0) {
        angle += 2 * Math.PI;
    }
    // Преобразуем радианы в градусы
    return angle * 180 / Math.PI;
}

console.log(angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees({x: 0, z: -1}, {x:  0, z: -1}));
console.log(angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees({x: 0, z: -1}, {x: -1, z: -1}));
console.log(angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees({x: 0, z: -1}, {x: -1, z:  0}));
console.log(angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees({x: 0, z: -1}, {x: -1, z:  1}));
console.log(angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees({x: 0, z: -1}, {x:  0, z:  1}));
console.log(angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees({x: 0, z: -1}, {x:  1, z:  1}));
console.log(angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees({x: 0, z: -1}, {x:  1, z:  0}));
console.log(angleBetweenVectorsInDegrees({x: 0, z: -1}, {x:  1, z: -1}));
```

Comment: noup, до сих пор выводит 45, -0, 90

Comment: @Leobuildru, запустите пример. Восемь векторов по часовой стрелке. Что-то не так?

Comment: ответ в комментах выше выдаёт: 225, 0, 270. 0 можно заменить на 180, осталось понять, почему он заместо 45 выводит 225

Comment: я запустил вашу программу, у меня вывело: -0, 6.911227119024681, 3.283862287906357. Мб проблема во входных данных? для теста я внёс поправку в вопрос.